# Macro works only in stepthrough or with one breakline in code, but not when run normally

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a problem with my macro that creates chart, it works well when I step through but restarts my Excel when I run it normally. Tried various things, nothing works. It was originally part of other macro, but I isolated it to another sub, thinking it may help, but it still crashes when isolated.

Do you guys know what may be causing this?

**EDIT1**: There is no error information, the excel just restarts

**EDIT2**: The problem seems to be caused by this part of code:

```
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Liczba Dni Promocji - Wykres"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 16
```

This is the code:

```
Sub StworzWykres()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.PrintCommunication = True

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim myRng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raport_LiczbaDniPromocji")

Set pt = ws.PivotTables("LDP_Tab1")

'delete existing charts
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    shp.Delete
Next shp
Set shp = Nothing

'ask if make a chart
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If MsgBox("Czy chcesz utworzyć wykres Liczby Dni Promocji?", vbYesNo, "Wykres") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'adding the chart
'Set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set myRng = ws.Range(Cells(19 + pt.RowRange.Rows.Count, 4), Cells(18 + 2 * (pt.RowRange.Rows.Count), 6))
myRng.Select
Set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
'Set chrt = ws.ChartObjects.Add.Chart
'chrt.Activate
With chrt
    'For j = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    '    .SeriesCollection(j).Delete
    'Next j
    '.SetSourceData Source:=myRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered
    '.SetSourceData Source:=myRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Parent.Name = "Wykres_LDP"
    .DepthPercent = 400
    .PlotArea.Format.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    .PlotArea.Format.ThreeD.RotationY = 110
    .RightAngleAxes = True
    .ChartArea.Left = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 6)).Width + 1 'ws.Cells(20 + pt.RowRange.Rows.Count, 8).Left - (ws.Columns(7).ColumnWidth / 1.25)
    .ChartArea.Top = ws.Cells(18 + pt.RowRange.Rows.Count, 8).Top
    .ChartArea.Height = ws.Range(Cells(19 + pt.RowRange.Rows.Count, 8), Cells(47 + pt.RowRange.Rows.Count, 8)).Height
    .ChartArea.Width = 1000
    .Parent.Placement = xlMove
    .ChartColor = 10
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 150
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    .Legend.Font.Size = 12
    .Legend.Font.Bold = True
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Liczba Dni Promocji - Wykres"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 16
    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .TickLabels.Orientation = 60
        '.TickLabels.Font.Bold = True
        '.TickLabels.Font.Size = 11
    End With
    For j = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        .SeriesCollection(j).HasDataLabels = True
        .SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
        .SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Font.Bold = True
        .SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Font.Size = 10
        If j = 1 Then
            .SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = 32
        Else
            .SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = 46
        End If
    Next j
    '.SetSourceData Source:=myRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
End With

'clear variables

Set ws = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing
Set myRng = Nothing
i = Empty
j = Empty

'Application.PrintCommunication = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, whats the error? The line... U must give more details...

Comment: But there is no error, Excel just restarts. After more digging, it turned out that the     `.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)

    .ChartTitle.Text = "Liczba Dni Promocji - Wykres"

    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True

    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 16`

is what causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
```

and insert

```
.HasTitle = True
```

in the same place.

Comment: Yep, it worked! Thank you very much. Could you tell my why is the `.SetElement` failing? I am almost sure I used it in other charts and it worked fine.

Comment: Who knows, Excel works in mysterious ways. All I know is, the `.SetElement` syntax was added many years and several Excel versions after I learned to do things the old way (like `.HasTitle = True` or `.Visible = True`, etc.), and the old ways seem more reliable and actually more self-explanatory than `.SetElement`.